# Prolog list question

Tags: list, prolog

I have a database consisting of the following rules;

```
speaks(fred [german, english, dutch]).
speaks(mary [spanish, arabic, dutch]).
speaks(jim [norwegian, italian, english]).
speaks(sam [polish, swedish, danish]).
```

etc

As part of a much larger program, how would I find out 3 people who speak the same language?

Jen

Comment: Shouldn't it be `speaks(fred, [german, english, dutch]).` (note the extra comma)?
Also: is this homework? If so, please tag it as homework.

Comment: It does have a bit of a homeworky smell to it.

Answer (score 3):

As it is, [Franz' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779045/prolog-list-question/1779139#1779139) will not work: it returns triples of prople which speak the same language, but these triples may contain duplicates. Thus one would still have to resort to e.g. [`sort/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort%2f2) and [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length%2f2) to find the answer to the original question:

```
?- findspeakers(Language, X1, X2, X3), sort([X1, X2, X3], Y), length(Y, 3).
false.
```

(So the answer is *no*, there are no three people speaking the same language.) Anyway, I think a more elegant solution exists:

```
spoken(L, S) :-
  speaks(S, LL), member(L, LL).

same_language(N, L, SS) :-
  bagof(S, spoken(L, S), SS), length(SS, N).
```

The predicate `spoken/2` uses [`member/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member%2f2) and succeeds if language `L` is spoken by person `S`. `same_language/3` succeeds if the list `SS` contains `N` distinct people, all of which speak language `L`. This predicate uses [`bagof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof%2f3); if the definition of the `speak/2` predicate contains duplicate data, then you should use [`setof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof%2f3) instead.

Observe that this nicely generalises the problem: we can now answer the question for *any* *n*, not just 3. Demonstration:

```
?- same_language(3, L, SS).
false.

?- same_language(2, L, SS).
L = dutch,
SS = [fred, mary] ;
L = english,
SS = [fred, jim] ;
false.
```

Comment: Wow. great answer. Yours exceeds my Prolog knowledge by a lot ;)

Comment: Yeah, mine as well. I've been meaning to learn how `bagof` and `setof` work, and this is a nice example to draw from.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, so there might be some syntax glitches, but I hope you get the idea...

```
% Find out whether an element is contained in a list
in_list(X,[X|_]).
in_list(X,[First|Rest]) :- in_list(X,Rest).

% Find out 3 people who speak the same language
findspeakers(Language, X1, X2, X3) :- speaks(X1, L1), speaks(X2, L2), speaks(X3, L3), in_list(Language, L1), in_list(Language, L2), in_list(Language, L3).
```

Pretty simple solution using list operators (I didn't remember whether there was a built-in rule for finding out whether a variable is contained in a list, so I rewrote it).

You can find out groups of three people speaking English with the following command:

```
findspeakers('English', X1, X2, X3).
```

You can find all groups of three people speaking a common language with the following command:

```
findspeakers(Language, X1, X2, X3).
```

**NOTE**: These commands will give you all possible combinations of groups of three people, so if you have four people speaking English, the first command will give you four result sets.

Comment: I could just be tired, but I think it will give 64 result sets in that case, as it's generating permutations with repetition allow, not combinations with repetition disallowed.

Comment: Also, there is indeed a predicate that does what your `in_list/2` does: `member/2`. I don't think it's in the ISO standard, but it should have near-universal support as an extension.

Comment: Ah, cool. Thanks for the comments. Especially the first one is very interesting - I didn't know that...

Comment: @Franz: aside from the syntax error (the semi-colon at the end of `findspeakers`), this does not really answer the question: `findspeakers` does not test whether the three speakers are distinct. Further, the problem can be generalized in a nice way. (See my answer.)

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error. Fixed it. Still: this does answer the question, as he was "only" asking 

That doesn't mean I don't like your answer better ;)

Comment: Oops. "...as he was 'only' asking for finding the three people" and I did solve that.

Missed that part.